# Remote desktop works only localy

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, dynamic-ip, dynamic-dns

Using Windows Server 2008 R2, I have configured a **simple remote desktop access** and IIS, then I used **my external IP address** to ensure that the **default IIS web page is reached**.

I connected **localy** to the server using Remote desktop and **succeeded**.
Then, I tried RDP with the same external address used to connect to the IIS and failed. FYI, I am using **dynamic-dns**.

I have also tried using the domain name: since **mydomain.com** is both the name of my machine and also the name of my web site, **and mydomain.com resolves normaly** the IP address.

I have tried to find in **Remote desktop Session host configuration** in Administrative tools, if is there a way to configure dynamic IP but failed, hard to find on google too.

Is there an idea on this please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to port forward TCP port 3389 to the server in the router/firewall.

Comment: I already configured the router -> firewall -> Virtual Servers -> fixed local IP address of the server -> to allow the RDP on its port number. You remember the port number changing question ?

Comment: Have you verified that the server is listening on that port for RDS?

Comment: Yes of course, do you remember Firewall predefined rule question, when it was question to change port number and create a new rule with the new number.

Comment: Yes, but that only addresses the firewall. RDS has to be configured to listen on the port. Have you done that? When you connect internally what port are you connecting to?

Comment: I have changed the port number in the registry, and I use the same port to connect localy, it works.

Comment: Also, I just made a telnet from my client machine to that port number, and failed.

Comment: Ok, then check the firewall rule and see what network profile it's set to allow for. Also, what network profile is the NIC on the server using?

Comment: Firewall rule is created only for TCP not for UDP and is set to allow all profiles. Sorry for the second question I cannot understand your meaning.

Comment: It would be great if you transfer this discussion to chat since I have not enough reputation.

Comment: OK. Are you sure that when you're connecting internally that you're connecting to the new listening port? How are you specifying the port when you connect?

Comment: Yes, I am currently connected internally to the fixed IP address 192.168.1.10, when connecting I provide the next: "192.168.1.10:xxxx"

Comment: And when you connect externally are you connecting like x.x.x.x:yyyy, where x.x.x.x is the public ip address and yyyy is the new port number?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: thank you very much for your valuable help, I've learned so much from you, finaly found the dysfunction source, it is caused by the recently  changed RDP listening port, which had to be set the same not only in the local port zone but also in the public port zone in the router firewall port forwarding.

Comment: OK, so it was a router/firewall issue. Good to know. Glad you got it working. cheers :)